# How to periodically check if any file changed and then build

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop

I would like to monitor directory for change and if any file in that directory changes then I would like to build software. How can I do it with a shell "oneliner" ?

I was trying some variations of

`watch "if [ find _source -mmin -1 ]; then make; fi"`

but it's not correct syntax.

Comment: Use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to monitor the activity of your directory

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/a/181543) answer should help.

Comment: But isn't make supposed to do that automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I ended up doing is

```
while inotifywait --exclude "\.(swp|~)"  -qqre modify _source; do make ; done
```

The swap files where a problem because each time I have opened a file with vim the build was triggering  and I wanted it only to be triggered after file change.

One more question: does anyone know if I can specify regex to match files that I would like to trigger the event ? E.g. `*.cpp` ?

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, use `inotifywait` (from `inotify-tools` package on Ubuntu):

```
while inotifywait -qqre modify,create,delete,move _source;do make;done
```

The issue with this method is that modifications during the make process won't be detected.
To solve this you can run two processes; the first one:

```
while inotifywait -qqre modify,create,delete,move _source;do touch trigger;done
```

And the other one:

```
while inotifywait -qqre create trigger
do while [ -f trigger ]
   do rm trigger; make
   done
done
```